# Linq2Twitter not returning results

Tags: linq-to-twitter

having some trouble with Linq2Twitter v3.0.2. After the line where I call SingleOrDefault it hangs indefinitely. If you need more information let me know. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
{
    CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore()
    {
    ConsumerKey = MyConsumerKey,
    ConsumerSecret = MyConsumerSecret,
    AccessToken = MyAccessToken,
    AccessTokenSecret = MyAccessTokenSecret
    }
};

var twtrContext = new TwitterContext(auth);

var results =
    from search in twtrContext.Search
    where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
          search.Query == "Obama" &&
          search.Count == 10
    select search.Statuses;

var tweets = results.SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to Twitter v3.0 is async. You should change your query like this:

```
        var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
        {
            CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore()
            {
                ConsumerKey = MyConsumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = MyConsumerSecret,
                AccessToken = MyAccessToken,
                AccessTokenSecret = MyAccessTokenSecret
            }
        };

        var twtrContext = new TwitterContext(auth);

        var searchResponse =
            await
            (from search in twitterCtx.Search
             where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                   search.Query == "Obama" &&
                   search.Count == 10
             select search)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```